# Heroku app linking to domain providers website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, heroku, dns

I'm in trouble.

I have this website which runs on heroku with a custom domain from another provider. I made the connection between the 2 with the correct DNS.

It seemed to work on my browser but it didn't work on other computers, and after clearing my cache it didn't work on mines either. When they visit the site it shows the domain providers website.

At first i thought it had something to do with ssl, cause i got errors saying your connection is not private. Then i changed **config_force_ssl** to false:

```
 # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false
```

It seems that the A records in my domain providers DNS settings link to IP addresses and Heroku doesn't support ip addresses. Or it could still be something ssl related.

Here is my **domain providers DNS**:

```
ftp.example.io - CNAME - example.io
www.example.io - CNAME - example-example.herokuapp.com
example.io - A - 91.184.0.100
localhost.example.io - A - 91.184.0.100
webmail.example.io - A - 91.184.0.100
*.example.io - A - 91.184.0.100
mail.example.io - A - 91.184.0.94
```

**Here is the domain i added on heroku**:

```
Domain name: example.io
DNS Target: example-example.herokuapp.com
```

I have no idea anymore about what it could be. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oké i fixed the issue. For the people that are struggling with it, here is how i did it:

**Step 1**

> Make a Cloudflare account, and add the bought domain to cloudflare and
>   transfer the DNS settings'

**Step 2**

> Add your domain to your heroku panel. On the heroku site, log in, go
>   to 'settings' press 'add custom domain'
>   `- Add both your domain 'www.example.com' and your root domain 'example.com'`

**Step 3**

> If you haven't changed your nameservers on your initial domain
>   provider to point to the cloudflare nameservers, please do so now. You
>   can find the cloudflare nameservers which are assigned to you on your
>   cloudflare panel under `'DNS' -> 'cloudflare name servers'`

**Step 4**

> Go to 'DNS' on your cloudflare account and `remove all records (A,
>   CNAME, ALIAS,TXT etc..).`
>   Now add  a `CNAME` record. The name should be your site '`www.example.com`' (with www) and it should point to your heroku app `example-example.herokuapp.com`

**Step 5**

> Create a Google Business account. And follow along with the
>   verification steps given by Google.

**Step 6**

> Log in at `admin.google.com` and go to '`domains`'. If you can't see
>   'domains' click on 'more elements'. Now click on '`change redirect`' and
>   make your root domain '`example.com`' redirect to '`www.example.com`'.

**Step 7**

> Go to your cloudflare panel and go to 'DNS', now `add 4 'A' Records`.
>   - All 4 of the 'A' records should have the name of your root domain  `'example.com'` and they should point to `216.239.32.21`,
>   `216.239.34.21`, `216.239.36.21`, `216.239.38.21`, which are the ip
>   addresses given by Google to make the redirects work.

*Side note*

> On cloudflare, the 'A' record statuses  need to be set to 'DNS Only'
>   and the 'CNAME' record statuses to 'DNS and HTTP proxy(CDN)'

**Step 8**

> On your rails app go to `production.rb` and make sure
>   `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:
>   'https://example-example.herokuapp.com' }` is set to
>   `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:
>   'example-example.herokuapp.com' }` so simply remove the 'https://'.
>
> And also `config.force_ssl` should be `false`
>
> **After you have done that make sure you upload the result to heroku.**

**Step 9**

> At cloudflare go to 'crypto' and make sure SSL is set to 'Flexible',
>   if not please change it now, it might take a few moments before the changes are completed by cloudflare.

**CONGRATULATIONS !!!!!!!!!!!!!**

> At this point your site should be up and running and working for both
>   your root domain aswell as for your full domain.

**EXTRA**

> *ONLY IF YOU WANT BUSINESS EMAILS BY GMAIL (eg. info@example.com)*
>
> On cloudflare go to 'DNS' and add `5 'MX' Records`.
>
> 1. `example.com`(your root domain) - point to `aspmx.l.google.com` with `priority 1`
> 2. `example.com`(your root domain) - point to `alt1.aspmx.l.google.com` with `priority 5`
> 3. `example.com`(your root domain) - point to `alt2.aspmx.l.google.com` with `priority 5`
> 4. `example.com`(your root domain) - point to `alt3.aspmx.l.google.com` with `priority 10`
> 5. `example.com`(your root domain) - point to `alt4.aspmx.l.google.com` with `priority 10`
>
> **Note:** The `TTL` should be set to '`1 hour`' for `all 'MX' records`.

**Now go out there and be the best version of yourself!!**

Answer (score 0):

You should create a CNAME record on the DNS provider : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Yeah i already did. recordname: www.example.com, type: CNAME, content: example.herokuapp.com

Comment: What is your website url and the heroku url ?

Comment: www.example.io and example-example.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0):

Heroku not supports DNS. But you can add custom domains and subdomains, and from your domain hosting settings, redirecting to Heroku app. Here is little shot from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sf6GhsVGcTQ)

```
#for domain
$ heroku domains:add www.example.com`
Adding www.example.com to example... done
>
#for subdomain
$ heroku domains:add blog.example.com`
Adding blog.example.com to example... done
```

Comment: I have already done that, the problem is that it's not working. when i type 'heroku domains' on terminal it says: =
Domain Name: example.io     DNS Target: 
       example-example.herokuapp.com.. so it's kinda working already.

Comment: 1st of all, do u have that domain examle.io ? Ist belongs to you ? If its, then goto yr domain settings to redirect your heroku app.

Comment: Also i have attached link to youtube watch it u can understand it better.

Comment: Yeah i have that domain.. and i already put the required CNAME to point to my herokuapp.com.. the A records and CNAME records are in my original post under 'domain providers DNS' and the domain name that i added via the heroku control panel is under 'Here is the domain i added on heroku:'.. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

Configure heroku domain name to `www.example.io`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i had already fixed the issue though and i've put up the answer here.